# Firebase messaging in background and foreground handing in other activity

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I receives firebase notification with sound when app is in background but unable to handle the message because when i click on notification it always open launcher screen. It not opens the activity where i mentioned pending intent.Also if the app is running foreground there is no sound upon notification received. kindly help me.

Comment: can you update your notification data in your question?

Comment: i am sending simply notification from firebase console. Notifification recived also on the device. But the problem is the data inside notification is not opening in my application.

Comment: Can you pls share your `MyFirebaseMessagingService` class file?